# Moving semantics of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++14, move-semantics, unique-ptr

Lets consider the following piece of code:

```
template<typename T>
void f(std::unique_ptr<T>&& uptr) { /*...*/ }
```

In another function:

```
void g()
{
    std::unique_ptr<ANY_TYPE> u_ptr = std::make_unique<ANY_TYPE>();
    f(std::move(u_ptr));
X:  u_ptr->do_sth(); // it works, I don't understand why. Details below.
}
```

I don't understand why `u_ptr` in line `X` is still alive.
After all I forced him to be moved (std::move).

```
---EDIT---
Ok, so now:
The code is still working:

class T{
    public:
    T(){}

    void show(){
        std::cout << "HEJ!\n";
    }
};

void f(std::unique_ptr<T> ref){
   ref->show();   
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<T> my;
    my->show();
    f(std::move(my));
    my->show(); // How is it possible. Now, f takes unique_ptr by value 


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show us that code to function `f`, but presumably it didn't move the pointer, even though it had permission to.

You passed the `unique_ptr` by reference. If function invocation actually moved it, then the function couldn't use it because it would be gone before the function had a chance to.

If you want function invocation to actually move the pointer, you need to pass the pointer by value, not be reference. That value would be a `unique_ptr` for it to be moved into. In that case, you should declare the function as taking a `std::unique_ptr<T>` instead of a `std::unique_ptr<T>&&`. Then you can actually invoke the move constructor when you call the function.

*Update*: With your latest change, the `unique_ptr` would no longer reference any valid object due to the move construction. You just never check that it does. Invoking a non-virtual method that doesn't access any member variables can work just the same whether the object is valid or destroyed because it doesn't need anything from the object. You also never made the `unique_ptr` actually point to anything.

Instead, make the `unique_ptr` point to something. After it's moved, try calling a virtual function or accessing a member whose value is changed by the destructor. Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class T{
    public:
    T() : valid (true) {}
    ~T() { valid = false; }

    bool valid;

    void show(){
        std::cout << "HEJ! " << valid << std::endl;
    }
};

void f(std::unique_ptr<T> ref){
   ref->show();   
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<T> my (new T); // Make it point to a new object
    my->show();
    f(std::move(my));
    my->show(); // Try to access


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But why he didn't move pointer? Should it be called move_constructors for call function?

Comment: You passed the `unique_ptr` by reference. There's nothing to move construct. If you want to invoke the move constructor, you have to pass the `unique_ptr` by value, not by reference. Then you can move construct that value.

Comment: *Now* your code has undefined behavior. Try calling a virtual function or accessing a member whose value is changed by the destructor. (You do that twice, since `my` never refers to a `T`.)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your call to `show` doesn't crash is because it doesn't use the `this` pointer (it doesn't try to modify or access a data member).

Try this:

```
class T{
    public:
    int v;
    T(){}

    void show(){
        v = 0;
        std::cout << "HEJ!\n";
    }
};
```

> void f(std::unique_ptr&& ref)

This is the answer when you initially had your `f` function taking a rvalue reference **&&**.

Your function takes a rvalue **reference**. Therefore, no new `unique_ptr` object is created yet, you are simply passing a `reference`.

Inside your `f` function, if you create a a local `unique_ptr`, with the parameter `uptr`, then finally `uptr` will be moved to create that new object.

```
template<typename T>
void f(std::unique_ptr<T>&& uptr)
{
     //move uptr into local_unique_ptr 
     //note that we have to use move again
     //because uptr has a name, therefore its a lvalue.
     auto local_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T>(std::move(uptr));
}
```

The important thing to always know is that `std::move` is simply a `static_cast`.

If you pass a `lvalue` to `std::move`, it returns a `rvalue`. If you pass a `rvalue`, it returns a `rvalue`. That's it.

Comment: That's because your show function doesn't access or modify a data member (therefore it never tries to use the this pointer), it's like if you called a static function. If you modify your show function to take modify a data member it will crash.

Comment: Ok, but unique_ptr.get() should be null ptr so how is it possible to call that function (show). Perhaps we have to know address of object ( this) and in fact is null pointer .

Comment: It is nullptr. I have modified my answer to make your program crash. Just calling a function with an invalid pointer doesn't make it crash, unless that function actually uses the this pointer.

Answer (score 1):

in the line `f(std::unique_ptr<T>&& uptr)` `uptr` is not an object - it's a reference. a reference which capable to catch temporeries and mutate them.

it's like asking why doesn't the object get cloned in the next example

```
void func(std::string& str);
std::string str_ = "yyy";
func(str_);
```

`str_` is passed by "regular" reference and won't get copied - this is what pass by reference means.

`std::move` only cast l-value to r-value-reference, which `uptr` in `f(std::unique_ptr<T>&& uptr)` can reference, it's a reference referencing an object. opposed to the common conception, `std::move` won't do any moving by itself, only casts the object to r-value-reference for the move constructor/assg. operator to kick in.

here, the pointer still holds valid data since it was not moved, only casted to r-value-reference.

if you want the object to move you have to declare the parameter as object, not reference : `f(std::unique_ptr<T> uptr)`

In your edit, you have undefiend behaviour, so everything may occure.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `f` may not in fact move the pointer. Merely taking an object by `&&` does not modify the object.

`u_ptr->do_sth()` may invoke a static member function or a member function that does not access the object (`this`) and this is why it does not crash.

Comment: *"(...) and this is why it does not crash."* though it's still UB

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Insightful comment. Have a cookie.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki But wait! Is it _undefined_ behaviour, or _unspecified_ behaviour? That is important here!

Comment: it's undefined behavior